# Teardown logic in Kent Beck's xUnit example

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, xunit

I've been working through Kent Beck's *Test-Driven Development By Example*, more specifically the xUnit example (Chapters 18-24). I have some questions about the teardown-functionality. Originally, the flow of a test run is implemented as a method `run()` on a class `TestCase` in the following way

```
def run(self):
    result = TestResult()
    result.testStarted()
    self.setUp()
    method = self.getattr(self, self.name)
    method()
    self.tearDown()
    return result
```

When this is done he leaves as an exercise to the reader to change the method `run()` so the teardown logic is executed even when `method()` fails.

In the next chapter (Dealing with Failure), however, the method `run()` gets expanded in order to register a test failure:

```
def run(self):
    result = TestResult()
    result.testStarted()
    self.setUp()
    try:
        method = self.getattr(self, self.name)
        method()
    except:
        result.testFailed()
    self.tearDown()
    return result
```

After this edit, the item concerning teardown logic is still open on the todo-list but to me the problem seems solved. The `except`-clause is as general as can be and the operation `result.testFailed()` will never throw an exception. Therefore it seems to me that, whatever `method()` may do, the teardown logic will *always* be executed. I can imagine putting the teardown in a `finally`-clause to better signify intent and to be a bit more robust against changes in `testFailed()`, but is this operation (and hence the exercise) redundant when `run()` has this form?

Answer (score 0):

It is an exercise that is supposed to help you learn. It prepares the stage for "Dealing with Failure".